Shimmer/Skeleton animation in Android Jetpack Compose
How can I create an animation like this to represent objects that are loading, thanks to everyone.
Shimmer example
I looked for the whole day but the information that I found was in views, if anyone knows a dependency or how to create this I will be thankful.

FWIW, searching for compose shimmer on major search engines will turn up many resources very quickly.

This question does not worth someone's research time. As this could be easily searched and there are plenty of websites with tutorials

The shimmer code works well, but it has a major recomposition issue. Here, I’ve optimized it using drawBehind to improve performance.
@Composable
fun Modifier.shimmerLoading(
    durationMillis: Int = 1000,
): Modifier {
    val transition = rememberInfiniteTransition(label = "")

    val translateAnimation by transition.animateFloat(
        initialValue = 0f,
        targetValue = 500f,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(
                durationMillis = durationMillis,
                easing = LinearEasing,
            ),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart,
        ),
        label = "",
    )

    return drawBehind {
        drawRect(
            brush = Brush.linearGradient(
                colors = persistentListOf(
                    Color.LightGray.copy(alpha = 0.2f),
                    Color.LightGray.copy(alpha = 1.0f),
                    Color.LightGray.copy(alpha = 0.2f),
                ),
                start = Offset(x = translateAnimation, y = translateAnimation),
                end = Offset(x = translateAnimation + 100f, y = translateAnimation + 100f),
            )
        )
    }
}

Using this is straightforward — just call it to the Modifier of your composable.
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(80.dp)
        .clip(CircleShape)
        .shimmerLoading()
)

I highly recommend checking out this Medium article titled: "Shimmer Animation in Jetpack Compose Without Recomposition" about creating a shimmer effect with no recomposition and optimized performance. It’s packed with great tips!

you can use rememberInfiniteTransition, for example simple shimmer animation below
val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition(label = "")
val skeletonAlpha by infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
    // between these states, the skeleton will flicker
    initialValue = 1f, // skeleton max alpha
    targetValue = 0.5f, // skeleton min alpha
    animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
    // every 500ms, but you can change this time 
        animation = tween(500, easing = LinearEasing),
        repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse
    ), label = ""
)
Card(modifier = Modifier.alpha(skeletonAlpha))


Accompanist placeholder api is deprecated. You can use the following structure instead.
@Composable
fun ShimmerEffectBox(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier, isShow: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit
) {
    val shimmerColors = listOf(
        Color.LightGray.copy(alpha = 0.6f),
        Color.LightGray.copy(alpha = 0.2f),
        Color.LightGray.copy(alpha = 0.6f)
    )

    val transition = rememberInfiniteTransition(label = "")
    val translateAnim by transition.animateFloat(
        initialValue = 0f, targetValue = 1000f, animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(durationMillis = 1700, delayMillis = 200),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart
        ), label = ""
    )

    val brush = Brush.linearGradient(
        colors = shimmerColors,
        start = Offset.Zero,
        end = Offset(x = translateAnim, y = translateAnim)
    )


    if (isShow) {
        Box(
            modifier = modifier.background(brush)
        ) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .matchParentSize()
                .graphicsLayer { alpha = 1f })
        }
    } else {
        Box(
            modifier = modifier
        ) {
            content()
        }

    }
}

Usage:
  Row {
            ShimmerEffectBox(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(100.dp)
                    .padding(4.dp)
                    .weight(0.3f)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)),
                isShow = true
            ) {

                Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background), contentDescription = "")
            }
            ShimmerEffectBox(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(100.dp)
                    .padding(4.dp)
                    .weight(0.7f)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)),
                isShow = true
            ) {

                Text(
                    text = "Content to display after content has loaded"
                )
            }
        }

